# How to numerically list a list view

Tags: android, firebase

In my application the users can input scores and they are stored in Firebase

```
myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Scores").child("Net_and_Gross_Scores_Week_17th_March _2018 ");
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> array  = new ArrayList<>();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        LeaderBoardScores uInfo = ds.getValue(LeaderBoardScores.class);
        array.add(" Net:" +uInfo.getNet() +  "  Name:" +uInfo.getFullName() + "   Gross:" + uInfo.getGross()+ "   Handicap:" + uInfo.getPlayerHandicap());


    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Is there a way to sort results from a firebase retrieval in a numerical way?
I want the results to be sorted in Net Score from lowest to highest?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a numerical way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you want to use:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Scores").child("Net_and_Gross_Scores_Week_17th_March _2018 ")
    .orderByChild("Net");
```

You can reverse your search order by reversing the `ArrayList` you store your children in. Before setting your `ArrayAdapter` add this line:

```
Collections.reverse(array);
```

The important part here is the `orderByChild` method. I just assumed that your score value is stored in a child called *"score"*, but you can of course adjust that to what it really is.

More information on ordering references [can be found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: As the name of item that I want it to be sorted by is Net 
Should this then be
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Scores").child("Net_and_Gross_Scores_Week_17th_March _2018 ")
    .orderByChild("Net");?

Comment: @AaronNicholl Yes, you have to use `orderByChild("Net")` then.

Comment: myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Scores").child("Net_and_Gross_Scores_Week_17th_March _2018 ")
                .orderByChild("Net");

Comment: Error:(48, 132) error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to DatabaseReference

Comment: @AaronNicholl You have to change the type of `myRef` from `DatabaseReference` to `Query` because it is a query. `Query myRef = ...`.

Comment: Perfect that works 
Just need to figure out now how to sort from lowest to highest instead of Hightest to Lowest

Comment: @AaronNicholl I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) you can find all the information you need to retrieve the data sorted.

For example, in your case

```
Query query = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Scores")
    .child("Net_and_Gross_Scores_Week_17th_March _2018 ").orderByChild("Net");
```

Comment: This is actually wrong and does not work. If you [take a look at the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#orderByKey()) you can see that `orderByKey()` does not take any parameters because it *orders by **key*** and the key does not have any name.

Comment: jesus, I got distracted while typing. Thanks for the report, I'm correcting it right now @creativecreatorormaybenot